# Ajax & PHP login form, issues with validation. Multiple troubles

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to turn my login form into a drop down using ajax and jquery.  So far I've got everything working except the ajax and error validation.

Currently the main issue I have is when a field is not entered, password for example.  The login box displays "this field is required" which is great, if I then click on submit again the input field disappears and the message remains.  I can't continue with login unless I refresh the page.

The other main issue is getting the error message from the php.  If I input the wrong password, the message doesn't get displayed.  The form submits, goes away and that's it.  When I select login again I can see the error message that should have been displayed previously.

On a plus side : A correct login combination works perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Both PHP and Function are pasted below.

```
function validLogin(){

$('.error').hide();
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == ""){
    $('label#usernameError').show();
    $('input#username').focus();
    return false;
}

$('.error').hide();
var password = $('#password').val();
if(password == ""){
    $('label#passwordError').show();
    $('input#password').focus();
    return false;
}

var params = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
var url = "loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#status").show();
$("#status").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />');


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: params,
    beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= 'checking...'  ;
    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    success: function(html) {
        $("#status").hide();
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= html;
        if(html=="success"){

            window.location = "index.php"

        }

    }
});
}


<?php
//check fields are filled in
if(empty($_POST) === false){

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

//validate fields
if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
    $errors[] = 'Your username and password are needed.';
}else if($users->userExists($username) === false){
    $errors[] = 'That username does not exist';
}else if($users->emailActivated($username) === false){
    $errors[] = 'You need to activate the account, please check your email.';
}else{

    //start login
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if($login === false){
        $errors[] = 'That username or password is invalid';

        if(empty($errors) === false){
            echo '<p>' .implode('</p<p>', $errors).'</p>';
        }

    }else{
        //destroy old session and create new - prevents session fixation attacks
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        //all details are correct - the method returns the id to be sotred as a session
        $_SESSION['id'] = $login;
        //send user to their home page
        echo "success";
        header('Location: userHome.php');
        exit();
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:  Just checked again, now if I leave any of the fields blank or if they are incorrect no error is displayed.  The second scenario above is constant unless correct details are provided.

Comment: what's `implode('</p<p>', $errors)` all about?

Comment: it displays the errors, they're contained within an array.  If the array is not empty this 'empties', 'displays' or 'implodes' the array making the erros visible.

Comment: but why are you joining the elements with `</p<p>`?

Comment: sh!t, thats not supposed to be like that.  Meant to be</p><p>. Amended, saved, updated, above error still remains.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: could you post the html for the form and it's container

Comment: It's suggesting chat, I can pastebin it if you don't mind?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33499/discussion-between-steve-green-and-ianbarker)